# Unable to design table with checkbox, alignment,

Tags: tables, line-breaking, tikz-styles, multirow

I am unable to decide the columns and rows of the table. Moreover, checkbox needs to inserted there so handling tikz creates a confusion with bars. [![Desired table][1]][1]
I am trying to design this form using latex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

% Set page size and margins
% Replace `letterpaper' with `a4paper' for UK/EU standard size
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

% Useful packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{multirow}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%Long Table%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}

\setlength\LTleft{0cm}
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.7cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}
\hline
  \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{\textbf{MEDICAL CERTIFICATE}} \\
  \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{\textbf{(to be issued by a Registered Medical Practitioner)}} \\ \hline
   \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{\textbf{\underline{GENERAL EXPECTATIONS}}} \\
   \multicolumn{6}{|l|}{hi hello} \\ \hline
  & & & & & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[![Work done till now][2]][2]

Moreover I am facing issue with line break in multi column and itemmize
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GWWU.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzdTQ.png

Comment: Please share what you have so far.  How closely are you trying to match the form?  The fact that the vertical lines don't match up is going to make things difficult.

Comment: @Teepeemm I have updated it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, finally, I did it on my own. I don't know how much precise I am. Still, I tried, and it worked for me. Thank you

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

% Set page size and margins
% Replace `letterpaper' with `a4paper' for UK/EU standard size
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

% Useful packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{multirow}


 %%%%%%%%%%%%%Long Table%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{align=left}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Multi-row%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{multirow}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%Long Table%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{longtable}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Check box%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newlist{todolist}{itemize}{2}
\setlist[todolist]{label=$\square$}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Signature%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

 \begin{center}

\setlength\LTleft{0cm}
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.5cm}|p{0.7cm}|p|p|p|p|}
\hline
  \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{\textbf{MEDICAL CERTIFICATE}} \\
  \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{\textbf{(to be issued by a Registered Medical Practitioner)}} \\ \hline
   \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{\textbf{\underline{GENERAL EXPECTATIONS}}} \\
   \multicolumn{6}{|l|}{\begin{minipage}{\hsize}% needed to remove gaps at top and bottom
   \vspace{1ex}
   Candidates should have good general physique. In particular,
  
    \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*,noitemsep]
        \item Chest measurement should not be less than 70 cm, with satisfactory limits of expansion and contraction.
        \item Vision should be normal. In case of defective vision, it should be corrected to 6/9 in both eyes or 6/6 in the better eye. Colour blind and uni-ocular (having vision in only one eye) persons are restricted from admission to certain courses.
        \item Hearing should be normal. Defective hearing should be corrected.
        \item Heart and lungs should not have any abnormality and there should be no history of mental illness and epileptic fits.
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{minipage}
   } \\ \hline
 1. & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{(a)} & \multicolumn{2}{p{11cm}|}{Name of the candidate: \newline} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{(b)} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Gender:} \\ \hline
 2. & \multicolumn{5}{p{11cm}|}{Identification Mark (a mole, scar or birthmark), if any \newline} \\ \hline
 3. & \multicolumn{5}{p{11cm}|}{Major illness/operation, if any (specify nature of illness/operation) \newline} \\ \hline
 4. & \multicolumn{2}{p{4.7cm}}{Height in cm:} & \multicolumn{3}{p{7cm}|}{Weight in kg:\hspace{1.1in} Blood Group:}  \\ \hline
 5. &\multicolumn{2}{p{2cm}}{Past History  \newline 
}& \multicolumn{3}{|p{7cm}|}{(a) Mental illness\newline(b) Epileptic Fit }  \\ \hline
 6. &\multicolumn{5}{|p{14cm}|}{Chest \hspace{0.2in} (a) Inspiration in cm\hspace{1in} (b) Expiration in cm }\\ \hline
 7. & \multicolumn{5}{|p{14cm}|}{Hearing}\\ \hline
 8. & \multicolumn{5}{p{10cm}|}{\begin{tabular}{p|p|p|p|p| } 
    \multicolumn{1}{p{3cm}|}{(Vision with or without glasses:)\newline} & \multicolumn{1}{p{2cm}|}{(Right Eye)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{2cm}|}{(Left Eye)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{2cm}|}{(Colour Blindness)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{3cm}}{Uniocular vision (having vision in only one eye)}
    \\ 
                    \end{tabular}}  \\ \hline
 9. & \multicolumn{5}{|p{14cm}|}{Respiratory System} \\ \hline
 10. & \multicolumn{5}{|p{14cm}|}{Nervous System} \\ \hline
 11. & \multicolumn{5}{|p{14cm}|}{Heart \hspace{0.2in} (a) Sounds\hspace{1in} (b) Murmur }\\ \hline
 12. &\multicolumn{2}{|p{3cm}}{Abdomen\newline (a)Liver\newline(b) Spleen\newline } & \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Hernia } &\multicolumn{2}{l|}{Hydrocele } \\ \hline
 13. & \multicolumn{5}{|p{14cm}|}{Any other defects: \newline} \\ \hline
 \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{\textbf{Certificate of Medical Fitness}} \\ 
 \multicolumn{6}{|l|}{\begin{minipage}{\hsize}% needed to remove gaps at top and bottom
   \vspace{1ex}
   
   \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
    \begin{todolist}
        \item The candidate fulfils the prescribed standard physical fitness, medical fitness and is FIT for admission to Engineering/Architecture/ Pharmaceutics/ Science Course
        \item The candidate does not fulfil the prescribed standard of physical fitness/medical fitness and is unfit/temporarily unfit for admission due to following defects: \newline
    \end{todolist}
  \end{itemize} 
  \vspace{1in}
   \begin{tabular}{ccccc} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick] (-3.5,1) -- (0,1);
\end{tikzpicture}& \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick] (-2.5,1) -- (0,1);
\end{tikzpicture} &  \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick] (-2,1) -- (0,1);
\end{tikzpicture}  &  \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick] (-3.1,1) -- (0,1);
\end{tikzpicture}  &  \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick] (-2.1,1) -- (0,1);
\end{tikzpicture}  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{p{3cm}}{~~Doctor's Name\newline} & \multicolumn{1}{p{2.5cm}}{~~Signature} & \multicolumn{1}{p{1cm}}{~~~~Date} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4cm}}{~~~~~Registration No.} & \multicolumn{1}{p{3cm}}{~~~~~~~Seal}
                    \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
   } \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```